Based on the scatter-plot that i have made to validate my regression model, that could be considered a good model?
I have a gradient-boost regressor model, i'm predicting value of sentences, which often are round numbers (which makes it annoying to validate).
I have created a scatter-plot to validate my model, x-axis is the real value and y-axis is the pred value, see below:

This plot evidences a problem, overestimation of low values and underestimation of high values, this is a problem hard to solve, specially because of the distribuition of the real data.
But, it shows a positive tendency line, which is usually a indicative of a decent/good model, what are yours thoughts? is that model decent/good because of the tendency line or not a good model because of the wide range of the vertical lines (the dots forming the vertical lines)?
Any idea about that or tips on other plots that i can make to validate this model, i will be greatfull to read.
Thanks!

What happens when you jitter the points? Its difficult to say, but this data looks like it may be nonlinear. With initial increases in the predictor, the association seems positive, but it also looks to flatten out as the predictor gets closer to it's maximum. Jittering the points will show this more clearly if this is the case.

This plot exhibits regression to the mean, which is a universal mathematical phenomenon in any scatterplot.  What, then, do you mean by "validate the model"??
